# Is there a way to achieve BLPOPX that only pop when key already exist?

Tags: redis

The BLPOP will block no matter the key exist or not. I need the "X" version that checks if the key exist, similar to LPUSHX, RPUSHX. If the key does not exist, the command is a no-op. I only want to pop from the list when an event happens. There is the EXIST command, but having two commands would not be atomic. Could I put these two commands into a lua script to run atomically? Is that going to hang redis since the command could block?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have some misunderstanding on the behavior of Redis LIST and BLPOP/LPOP command. If the the list is empty, the related key will be deleted automatically by Redis, i.e. the key does not exist if the list is empty.

> If the key does not exist, the command is a no-op.

That's what `LPOP` command does. If the key does not exist, `LPOP` returns a nil reply immediately. Otherwise, it pops an item from the list. However, in this case, you need to do the pooling work on client side.

> Could I put these two commands into a lua script to run atomically? Is that going to hang redis since the command could block?

You cannot do that. In fact, Lua script forbids those commands, e.g. `BLPOP`, that will block Redis.